# Qsort array of structs compare function

Tags: c, struct, qsort

Okay, I got this to work by looking around online and such, but can someone explain what lines numbered 1 and 2 do exactly and why they are needed

```
int structCompare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
     struct trade *tempA = (struct trade *)a;//(1)
     struct trade *tempB = (struct trade *)b;//(2)
     return strcmp(tempA->name, tempB->name);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Those lines cast the generic `void` pointers to `struct trade` pointers. The explicit cast is superfluous in C when `void *` is involved and should be eliminated:

```
 struct trade *tempA = a;
 struct trade *tempB = b;
 return strcmp(tempA->name, tempB->name);
```

You could have written:

```
return strcmp(((struct trade *)a)->name, ((struct trade *)b)->name);
```

I prefer the first one though.

Comment: Ohh, thank you. Seeing them not casted makes more sense. Also, thanks for the simplified version. Actually I have multiple layers of sorting in case the name field is the same, but I'll keep your one line solution in mind!